# Adobe Media Encoder (Why is it not using all the available power)

Tags: after-effects, encoding, adobe, adobe-media-encoder, rendering

**System Spec:**

```
16 core 3950x
Nvidia rtx 3080
64gb of ram
1tb nvme
2tb ssd
4tb hdd
```

**Software**

```
AfterEffects - v17.5.1 (build 47)
MediaEncoder - v14.7 (build 17)
```

**Problem:**

So I'm outputting a fairly complex render at 1080p 30fps and the media encoder is only using 3% of the CPU and 6% of the GPU. I have always had issues with rendering but this new pc I have just bought should be rendering much faster than the old setup but they are basically identical. Can someone explain if there is something I can do to increase the performance or explain why the hell this shit is like this?

Answer (score 0):

So after quite some time it turns out ame is pretty useless on using as much comp resources as you have. I did how ever find a really solid solution. Rendergarden is a third party tool that splits the output render into chunks and renders them all in parallel. I went from using no more than 3% cpu to render garden using as much as I asked ie 96%.

This axes render times by a factor I genuinely cannot believe. In real terms it cut a 3h 52min render into a 24min job. (16 CORES SMASHES THROUGH RENDERS)

It does cost money but if you are experiencing this issue this 100% removes the media encoder render bottleneck.

Comment: If you think this is a useful answer, you should set the "accepted answer" check mark.  That way the system won't keep asking people to provide a better answer, and people with a similar question will notice that this one has an answer that's marked as useful. and so be more likely to read it.